# Rails simple_format and display of 'Read More' link inline with text

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

Should have been very easy but somehow cannot get it to work. I want to display truncated text on my blog home page with a 'read more' link that shows up inline with the text i.e.

*Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris ac tortor et felis aliquet vestibulum sed in sem. Aliquam pharetra ultricies nunc, non pellentesque ... **Read More***

Since I use simple_format for my text, all breaks in the text get wrapped in

tags and I get Read More in a separate line as below

*Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris ac tortor et felis aliquet vestibulum sed in sem. Aliquam pharetra ultricies nunc, non pellentesque ...*

***Read More***

How do I place it inline after a < p > tag. Guess it's more of a CSS question rather than a Rails one. Again, I feel this should be super simple. What am I forgetting?

Here's the code snippet in the view

```
<%= simple_format truncate(h(feed.description), length: 400, separator: ' ') %><%= link_to "Read More", feed_path(feed)%>
```

Comment: what does your view code currently look like?

Comment: Yes, please show us the code so we can show you how to alter it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you can just put your link inside the simple_format content-parameter link this:

```
<%= simple_format truncate((h(feed.description) + link_to("Read More", feed_path(feed))), length: 400, separator: ' ') %>
```

(Note: not tested)